# Best way to have your node connect to a URL (DDNS)

Tags: node

The node I need to connect to has a variable IP. I've set up a Dynamic DNS service and use the following workaround to connect to it:

```
./tezos-admin-client connect address $(host myddnsaddress.net | awk '/has address/ { print $4 ; exit }'):9732
```

Is there a better way to have your node connect to an URL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything better than using `tezos-admin-client connect`, but you could get the address more directly with `tezos-client-connect $(dig +short myddnsaddress.net):9732`.